# Retrieve data from Wordpress in my Android Application

Tags: android, wordpress

I need to access Wordpress posts (Outside) from my Android Application. I need to display somehow the last post ( Maybe Titles in a listview), and edit some of them by entering new text, picture and video.

I came across many explanations about how to do that in php. But since I'm working with Andoird. I need it in Java

Any idea how to do that ??

Comment: And how would you do that in php?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the official Wordpress app for Android: http://android.wordpress.org/development/

Comment: @agamov : Check this out : http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/xml-rpc-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with WordPress, but I can suggest you to start with RSS-parsing of your posts (WordPress provides RSS, right?).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to access the WordPress database. I am not 100% familiar with WordPress but I think the posts are stored in the table wp_posts. You should also be able to find, access, and edit any data within.

Answer (score 0):

I Know buddy What you Want to do with Wordpess and Android Application. i Can give you Some Scripts..

**Download SVN Grabber**

downloadsvn.codeplex.com/

**Download Wordpress Android Source Code from wordpress.**

android.svn.wordpress.org/

**You can do Your Task using Wordpress Rest Api
Documentation**

developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

**Wordpress XML-RPC Api**

codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API

**I also Working with Android Native Application via Wordpress**

Comment: Can you be more specific please. Or maybe explain how to link all these tools you kindly proposed ? Thank you :)